# Чтение RTF с таблицей на Java

Tags: java, rtf

Есть некий rtf-файл, содержащий в себе большущую таблицу. Пользуясь стандартной библиотекой прочитать файл с возможностью "обозначить" эту таблицу не нашел. Облазил тонны сторонних, так и не нашел ту, где есть возможность именно прочитать файл.

Посоветуйте библиотеку или решение данной проблемы. С Java, к сожалению, знаком крайне скудно, но этот функционал необходим по ТЗ.